# Count word occurrence

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm having a problem with the logic in my program, I want this program to only display each word once and the number of times they occur. The error in my logic is at the second for loop with the strcmp.

At the moment it checks every string individually and if they are not the same it copies it into the string array. However, this logic is not right because unless I enter the same word every time there will always be a string that is different.

For example if I enter

> hello how are are you today

I want it to display just

```
word: hello times: 1
word: how   times: 1
word: are   times: 2
word: you   times: 1
word: today times: 1
```

My program will display

```
word: hello times: 1
word: how   times: 1
word: are   times: 2
word: are   times: 1
word: you   times: 1
word: today times: 1
```

Is there any way to fix my logic?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 200
#define COL 20

int read_input(char *str, int n);

int main(void)
{
    char input[ROW];
    char tokens[ROW][COL+1] = {{0}};
    const char *s= " ,";    
    char *pch;
    int count[ROW] = {0};
    int i, j = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;

    // read input from user
    read_input(input, ROW);

    // break input into tokens
    pch = strtok(input,s);

   while (pch != NULL) {
        wordCount = i;

        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            // compare tokens with array
            if (strcmp(pch, tokens[j]) != 0) {
                strcpy(tokens[i], pch);         
                count[i++] = 1;
            }
            // if tokens are the same increment word
            else
                count[j]++;
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL,s);

    }

    for ( i =1 ; i <= wordCount; i++ ) {
        printf("COL #: %d Word: %s\t Times: %d\n",i, tokens[i], count[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " if they *are* not the same it copies it into the string array." - that's not what it does.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if you had comments in the code. Also, you should try to avoid `#define` for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop makes a change to `count` on *every* iteration.  Instead, it should loop until either it has found a match (at which point it can increment that word's `count` and stop looping) or, if it finishes the loop never having found a match, only then add it to the list of `token`s.

Also, if there are any matches, then the number of words in `token` will be less than the number of words in the string, which means you need different variables to track each of those.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `std::map<string, int>`. Where the string is a key "unique" in the map and the int would be its counter.