# How can I get the text input from the user and count the words i am searching

Tags: c

I am using fgets to get a sentence from the user and i am trying to get words and count on c code then print it. 
Exapmle: i want to count "Hello". When the program starts user write "Hello World Hello" and then the program prints "Hello used 2 times".

Comment: And where are you blocked ? What is your question ?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a wishing well where you throw in requests and get code back.

Comment: Please do searching before you ask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35960478/count-word-occurrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `scanf`-function to get text input from the user; the function will put it into a `char` array. (You would ask the user for the sentence as well as the word you are looking for)
Then you could use the [KMP-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to search for the given word in the sentence and just count the times the algorithm finds your word.